# how can I find Java Card products?

Tags: hardware, rfid, nfc

I am searching for hardware to help me get started with passive NFC [Java Card 3.2 technology](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javacard/3.2/index.html).
I can't find badges or tags or any kind of NFC product that advertises running Java Card 3.2.
I couldn't find anything on oracle.com, but is there an industry coalition or standards body with an information page, or OEM registry, or marketplace with clearly labeled breadcrumbs?

1. Does a Java Card 3.2 product even exists?
2. How else might I be able to obtain a device that perhaps could be modified (easily? ) to run Java Card?
3. Are any companies working on a passive NFC Java Card 3.2 product?

Comment: ACS have JavaCard 3.0.4 cards. You could ask them about 3.2.